# Pattern matching with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regex pattern which matches a word/character a space and then comma seperated values with or without spaces before and after. I have found difficulty making a pattern which did this and was wondering if someone could help me.
Example of what it should match:
`ages 19, 43,91`

I was trying something like this, `"(^[^\s])([^,]+)+"`, but it only matched the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pattern:

```
\S+(?:\s*\d+\s*,?)+
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/YaonKX/1)

---

- `\S+` - this will match one or more non-whitespace characters
- `(?:\s*\d+\s*,?)+` - non-capturing group.

  - `\s*` - match 0 or more whitespace characters
  - `\d+` - match 1 or more digits
  - `\s*` - match 0 or more whitespace characters
  - `,?` - optionally match `,`
- `+` - You may repeat this non-capturing group 1 or more times